# pod spec lint error: could not build module 'Protobuf', file not found: #import "google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h"

Tags: cocoapods, protobuf-c

I want push some code into master pod, this code depend on `Protobuf`.

```
s.dependency 'Protobuf', '3.3.0'
```

I had tried the follow three method to resolve it. But I failed.

```
   # method 1
   s.xcconfig = {
     # we have a math.h which conflicts with the system math.h unless
     # we disable header maps
     'GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS' => "1",
  }
  # method 2
   s.compiler_flags = '-GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1'
  # method 3
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS' => '1' }
```

The follow is my spec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'KSAdSDK'
  s.version          = '2.0'
  s.summary          = 'KSAdSDK.'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!


  s.homepage         = 'http://xxxx/KSAdSDK'
  # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'xxxxx' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'http://xxx/KSAdSDK.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

  s.requires_arc = false
  s.requires_arc = ['xxxx/**/*.m']

  s.source_files = 'xxx/**/*'

  s.public_header_files = 'xxxx/*.h'
  s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MobileCoreServices', 'CoreGraphics', 'Security', 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreTelephony', 'AdSupport', 'CoreData', 'StoreKit'
  s.library = "z"
  s.dependency 'AFNetworking'
  s.dependency 'SDWebImage'
  s.dependency 'MJExtension'
  s.dependency 'Godzippa'
  s.dependency 'Protobuf'
end
```

I use

```
pod lib lint --verbose --allow-warnings
```

and failed.

```
fatal error: 'google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h' file not found
     #import "google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
    'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' =>
      'GPB_USE_PROTOBUF_FRAMEWORK_IMPORTS=1 '
 }
```

Full example at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseMessaging.podspec